# How to handle "When will X be released?" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, scope

I see many questions on Stack Overflow like the title, asking when a new version of some software or library will be released. Are those kind of questions appropriate for Stack Overflow? Should I flag them and if so, what kind of flag?

Comment: That's one of those questions where I miss the "too localized" close reason. I'd tend to vote to close it with a custom reason, or perhaps as a request for an "off site resource". To me they are not appropriate for SO, given that either the official statement from the company will be out there, or we're only speculating, or the product has been released and your question is no longer relevant.

Comment: Related: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/2675154).

Comment: primarily opinion based unless there's some valid announcement of the date.

Comment: I'd always go with *request for an "off site resource"*...whether there's a date announced or not.

Comment: Dates change so I would just close as POB.  Even a published date is not certain.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not at all what the close reason is for. Even when a date is uncertain, it is not an opinion.

Comment: @Stijn Then what is it?  As far as I am concerned it is the answers opinion that X will be released on Y date.  It is not a fact because until the product is released it id a guess or educated guess but not a fact.

Comment: This is probably one of the best uses of the custom close reasons.  There is not one perfect close reason (off site resource might be the best fit and even that is a stretch), but the questions are off-topic mostly because of the reasons @Bart mentioned initially.  They are only speculation until officially announced (and once release the question has no value at all).

Comment: Note that the OP does not yet have the VTC privilege, so the question is how to flag. Custom moderator flags require the intervention of diamond moderators. I think it would be good if we agreed upon a flag for these cases, that can be handled by more people than only the diamond moderators.

Comment: As long as you flag as non-dupe vtc, others will see the post in the close queue.

Answer (score 4):

They are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, close them.

psubsee2003 suggested using a custom close reason.  You could take this approach and vote to close the question with the reason "We are not support for `<Company/Product>`."

Personally, I also use the POB ("primarily opinion-based") close reason for questions like these.  For example, if the question is "When will Swift 4 be released?" I would VTC the question as POB and add a comment: "I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based because this question can only be answered by members of Apple and the Swift dev team, and answers can only be based on speculation, not fact.

If the user does not have the Close Vote privilege, POB or off-topic flags should be used.